# Getting error while running jess in java program.

Tags: java, jess

I got error While running the jess in java program like 
 error: package jess does not exist
I don't know what and all packages to be included.

I have written code like this:

```
import jess.*;
public class ExQuery {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws JessException {
        Rete engine = new Rete();
        engine.batch("query.clp");
        engine.reset();

    QueryResult result =
        engine.runQueryStar("search-by-name", new ValueVector().add("Smith"));
    while (result.next()) {
        System.out.println(result.getString("fn") + " " + result.getString("ln")
                            + ", age" + result.getInt("age"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not getting. I imported com.boris.app.*.Got error like,

Comment: error: package com.boris.app does not exist

Comment: @BoristheSpider Try to know the subject before you post random comments. `jess` is indeed a package and contains class Rete (and others), and so the import is perfectly fine.

Comment: How is you class path setting? Does it include /.../Jess71p2/lib/jess.jar?

Comment: This is the sort of basic Java development question that is best answered by talking to someone locally -- a teaching assistant, another student; someone with a little experience using whatever development environment you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've imported the jess.jar librairy into your project.
Right click on project ->  Properties -> Into Java Build Path -> Add external JARs

you need to select the jess.jar file into your Jess71p2 (or other version..) -> lib -> jess.jar